# New account not redirecting

Tags: bug, login, stack-exchange-openid

So when I create a new account using gmail on a site while looking at a question, I get redirected back.
[image]
However, it seems that using the stackexchange login is bugged. Even if I'm looking at a question, it redirects me to the home page.[image]

This is shown in the address bar.